# .htaccess rules not doing what's expected in WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We had several WordPress sites which have been consolidated into a multi-site installation. But we consequently have a number of links to content that no longer work because the consolidated sites are now subdomains of the main, new, site. So we created a number of redirect rules in the site's .htaccess file.

We have the following (among others) rules in our .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://sub.newsite.com/$4 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.newsite.com/ [R=301]
```

Here's the problem: If the second rule is commented out, the first rule works; if the second rule is not commented out, it fires but the first rule seemingly does not.

The first rule matches posts of permalink structure `/yyyy/mm/dd/postname` on `http://oldsite.com` to just `/postname` on `http://sub.newsite.com/`. The second rule is supposed to catch all other URLs referencing the old site - which have not been explicitly referenced and redirected by other rules - and redirect to the newsite.

What am I not understanding here, and how should I fix this to achieve desired results? Thank you much.

Comment: You only have one rule in the code, but mention a "first" and a "second" rule?

Comment: Sorry - the first "rule" is the RedirectMatch, the second actual rule is the "RewriteRule".